# Problem creating a new Directory object in Oracle - ORA-20900: Invalid path used for directory

Tags: oracle, amazon-rds, oracle12c

I have an Oracle database hosted in AWS RDS.

In the course of dealing with some export (expdp) tasks, I am wondering what files exist in the directory that DATA_PUMP_DIR points to, and how big they are.

I found this command in the AWS docs:

```
select * from table(RDSADMIN.RDS_FILE_UTIL.LISTDIR('DATA_PUMP_DIR')) order by mtime;
```

It gives me 3 records:

```
bbr-imp-meta.log    file        14522   15-SEP-17
bbr-imp-data.log    file        1195    16-SEP-17
datapump/           directory   4096    09-JUL-20
```

How can I see what files are in that subdirectory `datadump`? I tried to create a new Directory object pointing to that path, in order to run the above command on the new Directory object, but I get this error:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
CREATE DIRECTORY DATA_PUMP_DIR_SUBDIR1
  AS '/rdsdbdata/datapump/datapump'
Error report -
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-20900: Invalid path used for directory: /rdsdbdata/datapump/datapump
ORA-06512: at "RDSADMIN.RDSADMIN_TRIGGER_UTIL", line 404
ORA-06512: at line 2
00604. 00000 -  "error occurred at recursive SQL level %s"
*Cause:    An error occurred while processing a recursive SQL statement
           (a statement applying to internal dictionary tables).
*Action:   If the situation described in the next error on the stack
           can be corrected, do so; otherwise contact Oracle Support.
```

What is that telling me? It looks like the path doesn't exist? Am I interpreting things incorrectly? Is it something to do with privileges? Does it matter which DB user creates the Directory object? I'm new to this.

Edit: On further investigation, it seems that [RDS restricts the creation of directory objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.Oracle.CommonDBATasks.Misc.html#Appendix.Oracle.CommonDBATasks.NewDirectories). An AWS procedure must be used for this, and it looks like I can't specify a path explicitly: "The system chooses the actual host pathname automatically." In which case, how can I access this subdirectory in an RDS-hosted Oracle DB? I wonder where the subdirectory even came from in the first place.

Edit 2: I am now beginning to suspect that there is no subdirectory at all. I ran this query...

```
select * from all_directories order by directory_path;
```

and amongst the results, there are 5 directory objects, created (I think) by an ex-teammate of mine:

```
SYS SANDBOX_DATA_PUMP_DIR   /rdsdbdata/userdirs/01  0
SYS PREPOD_DATA_PUMP_DIR    /rdsdbdata/userdirs/02  0
SYS PREPROD_DATA_PUMP_DIR   /rdsdbdata/userdirs/03  0
SYS DM_DATA_PUMP_DIR    /rdsdbdata/userdirs/04  0
SYS PS_DATA_PUMP_DIR    /rdsdbdata/userdirs/05  0
```

If I run the `RDSADMIN.RDS_FILE_UTIL.LISTDIR` procedure on each of these directory objects, there is always a result with `type` `directory`, with a name that matches the `directory_path` listed in `all_directories` for that directory object. I suspect that this result from `RDSADMIN.RDS_FILE_UTIL.LISTDIR` just references the path that the directory object itself points to. Pity there isn't some better documentation available from AWS on `RDSADMIN.RDS_FILE_UTIL.LISTDIR`...

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
ORA-20900: Invalid path used for directory: /rdsdbdata/datapump/datapump
```

indicates that error isn't a *built-in* Oracle exception, but one designed by developer (who have error codes from -20000 to -20999 available for their own purposes).

Who was it? This:

```
ORA-06512: at "RDSADMIN.RDSADMIN_TRIGGER_UTIL", line 404
```

suggests that `RDSADMIN` user owns "something" named `RDSADMIN_TRIGGER_UTIL` (query `user`/`all`/`dba_objects` to find what it is) which raised an error. Might be a trigger, or maybe a package ... can't tell.